# Regression Method Used in statsmodels adfuller()?

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels, reversion

What is the method of regression used in `adfuller()`? I'm performing an augmented dickey fuller test on a time series, and I'm trying two different ways of doing it.

First, I use `pandas.diff()` to get the change in price `dy`. Then I'm passing the original time series as an independent variable `y` along with `dy` as the dependent into `statsmodels.OLS(dy,y)` and getting the results. Then, I extract the slope parameter, `model.params[1]` and the standard error of the slope parameter `model.bse[1]`. The quotient of these terms is the Dickey Fuller test statistic I call `DF = model.params[1]/model.bse[1]`.

Second, I pass the singular time price series into `adfuller()` as such:

```
adfstat, pvalue, critvalues, resstore = ts.adfuller(y.y,regression='c',store=True,regresults=True)
```

Now, to get the Dickey Fuller test statistic, I simply pass
`DF = resstore.tvalues[1]`

Using OLS I get:

```
DF = -1.81495580198
```

With adfuller():

```
DF = -1.56386414181
```

I'm wondering what is the difference between these two methods? Does adfuller() perform a different linear regression than OLS internally? I've observed that the results from OLS are undeniably correct according to a book that I'm getting examples from. But I prefer to use adfuller() because it provides the critical values for the test statistic as a part of the output. Additionally, it seems that there are many regression coefficients for the adfuller() result:

```
print resstore.resols.params ==> 
[-0.00491391  0.02366782 -0.00295179  0.01354619  0.06399901 -0.06018851
 -0.00328142 -0.03876784  0.02934003 -0.10224276  0.00227549  0.01042279
 -0.04627873  0.05503934 -0.02707106  0.02664511 -0.02428741  0.04894767
 -0.06206492  0.00508655]
```

I determine the halflife for mean reversion by getting the slope of the regression line. It looks here that `adfuller()` is computing a 20th order regression? This doesn't seem right. Maybe I'm doing this wrong though? Can somebody shed some light on `adfuller()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by setting the maxlag=1 in the input for adfuller()